# How to move current record from a form to another form in access?

Tags: forms, record, ms-access-2013

I would like to move the current record meaning all the field for the current person in that form to another form which is one table to another table via forms. Using one command button. How can I do that?

I am thinking to use add & delete action to put in one button as it look like another way of moving too. But I have no ideas how to put only one record which is from the current person in that form. something like "current session"

In access.

Comment: take datarow from source .. put into target .. delete datarow from source

Comment: @matzone can you explain more detail? thanks.

Comment: sure, basically I have this form call the member and i would like to add a command to move this person to non-member table. such that all the fields are the same. @matzone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic step ..

Assume that you have Datagrid control named dgvMember in Form1 and dgvNonMember in Form2

You can create button named btnMoved that have click event like this ..

```
Private Sub btnMoved_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMoved.Click

//retrieve currentrow info from dgvMember -- all column as datagrid.row

//put the retrieved row to dgvNonMember -- directly to table/datasource

//it's now safe to delete selected row in dgvMember

End Sub
```

Comment: But where can i create datagrid control? From command button, code builder?? and do i paste the whole code there or? @matzone

Comment: datagridview control created usually at design time .. set datasource table could be at design time or in runtime .. there's many references about datagridview and you have to learn it practically .. About the above code is only the main think you should know to reach what you need ..

Comment: but is at a form how do I paste the code? I am a noob at access actually.

Comment: Sorry @user2294159, Stackoverflow recommend not to extended discussion in comments .. better you give some code link

Comment: meaning i can only talk to u from here ?